# Which one is better? 'not enough' or 'no enough'

Tags: phrase-usage

Can I use both of these sentences?

> There's no enough data to show.
>
> There's not enough data to show.

If I can use both of them, what is difference between them in meaning?

Comment: Only with something like a Scottish dialect could the first sentence come close to being idiomatic—and for that to be the case, it would instead be *there's **nae** enough data to show*, with *nae* being something that's regionally correct rather than a word in universal use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "not enough data" sentence is correct.  The "no enough data" sentence is not correct.

The critical word here is "enough", which works only with "not".

However, if there is no data at all, then you would say "There is no data".  In this case, you could not use "not".

To summarise, the following sentences are correctly expressed.

- There is **not enough** data.
- There is **insufficient** data.
- There is **enough** data.
- There is **no** data.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.

Comment: But I thought that `There is no enough-data` is also right. In my sentence `enough data` is used as `data` in your answer.

Comment: @Antonio - I assure  you: "There is no enough data" is most definitely **not** correct.

Comment: The "no" is an absolute, whereas "not" is a qualifier of "enough".

Comment: I think another option can be "There's not any data" right?